# Type Mismatch using LOOP/IFERROR/INDEX/MATCH

Tags: excel, vba, loops, indexing, match

What I am trying to do is looping through all rows and columns to find the quantity of a part inside a machine. This is searched for based on the article number and the Equipment/machine type. As in this screenshot:[image: Please see screenshot.]

My problem is that the way I have it running now is VERY slow. In the screenshot above is only a small portion of the cells. They go down to +-500 equalling roughly 22500 times the formula:

```
=ifERROR(INDEX(Datasheet!$B$1:$E$100;MATCH(1;(Datasheet!$D:$D=C$1)*(Datasheet!$B:$B=$AY15);0);4);"")
```

I want to speed it up using VBA by just giving my static values in all cells.
I have a large part done which I will display below.

The search values (datasheet)
[image: The search values (datasheet) is located in this image.]

I have it almost complete (I can feel it!) but it keeps returning me the type 13 Type mismatch error. I have found MANY MANY threads on stack overflow and the internet but these fixes do not fix it for myself.

My code:

```
'set all sheets
'----------------------------------------
Dim Isht As Worksheet
Dim Esht As Worksheet
Dim Dsht As Worksheet
Dim Gsht As Worksheet

Set Isht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Instructionsheet")
Set Esht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Exportsheet")
Set Dsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Datasheet")
Set Gsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Gathersheet")
'----------------------------------------

Dim EshtLR As Long
Dim EshtLC As Long
Dim DshtLC As Long
Dim DshtLR As Long

Dim OutputRange As Range
Dim SearchRange As Range
Dim MachineMatchCOL As Range
Dim ArticleMatchCOL As Range
Dim MachineType As String
Dim ArticleNumber As String

Dim StartRow As Long
Dim StartCol As Long

StartCol = Dsht.Range("P10").Value
StartRow = Dsht.Range("P11").Value

'Determine Last column in export sheet.
EshtLC = Esht.Cells(14, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'Determine Last row in data sheet.
DshtLR = Dsht.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'Determine Last row in export sheet.
EshtLR = Esht.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set OutputRange = Esht.Range(Esht.Cells(StartRow, 3), Esht.Cells(EshtLR, EshtLC - 9))
Set SearchRange = Dsht.Range(Dsht.Cells(1, 2), Dsht.Cells(DshtLR, 5))
Set MachineMatchCOL = Dsht.Range(Dsht.Cells(1, 4), Dsht.Cells(DshtLR, 4))
Set ArticleMatchCOL = Dsht.Range(Dsht.Cells(1, 2), Dsht.Cells(DshtLR, 2))

'=IFERROR(INDEX(Datasheet!$B$1:$E$100;Match(1;(Datasheet!$D:$D=C$1)*(Datasheet!$B:$B=$AY15);0);4);"")
'Datasheet!$B$1:$E$100 = SearchRange
'Datasheet!$D:$D = MachineMatchCOL
'Datasheet!$B:$B = ArticleMatchCOL
'C$1 = MatchineType
'$AY15 = ArticleNumber

j = StartRow
i = StartCol

For Each Row In OutputRange
        For Each Column In OutputRange
        MachineType = Esht.Range(Esht.Cells(1, i), Esht.Cells(1, i)).Value
        ArticleNumber = Esht.Range(Cells(j, EshtLC - 5), Cells(j, EshtLC - 5)).Value

        Esht.Cells(j, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction _
        .IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction _
        .Index(SearchRange, Application.WorksheetFunction _
        .Match(1, (MachineMatchCOL = MachineType) * (ArticleMatchCOL = ArticleNumber), 0), 4), "")
        i = i + 1

        Next Column
    j = j + 1
Next Row
```

It has something to do with the fact that a range cannot equal a value but I have tried for a long time and cannot figure it out.

Also note that the loop probably does not work but that is for a next problem to deal with :-).

I do not expect you to fully create everything but, again, a friendly push is also greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** The line that arises error is:

```
Esht.Cells(j, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction _
        .IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction _
        .Index(SearchRange, Application.WorksheetFunction _
        .Match(1, (MachineMatchCOL = MachineType) * (ArticleMatchCOL = ArticleNumber), 0), 4), "")
```

Comment: What line does it give that error?

Comment: ```Esht.Cells(j, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction _
        .IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction _
        .Index(Range1, Application.WorksheetFunction _
        .Match(1, (MachineMatchCOL = MachineType) * (ArticleMatchCOL = ArticleNumber), 0), 4), "")```

Comment: `.Index(Range1, Application.WorksheetFunction _` ... hmm where are you setting `Range1` ?. Use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code, it will help identify undeclared variables. I'm guessing you've meant to use `SearchRange` instead?

Comment: Also, as far as I know, `Match` fot 3 parameters. First one is a value, second one is a range, and 3rd one is boolean (optional). But in your code you typed `Match(1, (MachineMatchCOL = MachineType) * (ArticleMatchCOL = ArticleNumber), 0)` The part `(MachineMatchCOL = MachineType) * (ArticleMatchCOL = ArticleNumber)` will return just 1 or 0, in which any case is a range type, so there is no place for `Match` to search.

Comment: Eddited my Post. ```Range1``` should have been ```SearchRange```.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Match searches for 1, which is TRUE so it should find some value, right? The function itself works in Excel.

Comment: My opinion is that you are trying to resolve a prolem in VBA the same way you would do it in Excel... which kind of defeats the purpose, you could just drag the formula accross (or insert the formula via VBA if that's the intention). Read a bit about the arrays, load your data in an array and loop over that instead and do your logic there. Even if you loop inside of the loop on multiple levels, it will still be much much faster than reading back and forth from the spreadsheet.

Comment: @DarXyde Yeah I could drag it accross which I do right now, but this is a small part of my total code and when I let my code calculate it takes roughly 15-20 minutes for this 'part' ALONE. Which is waay too long. I hope that if VBA gives me static values it speeds things up.

Comment: The only way that you could find a `True` value in `(MachineMatchCOL = MachineType) * (ArticleMatchCOL = ArticleNumber)` is only when `MachineMatchCOL = MachineType` and `ArticleMatchCOL = ArticleNumber` at same time. So maybe you could change your code to check for that first with an `If ... And...` and then later on calculate your value.

Comment: The speed problem is mainly because you are accessing the spreadsheet `for each` cell, with a heavy formula... hence the suggestion of using an array. With an array, you would only need to access the spreadsheet twice, read and write... (the less, the better).

Comment: @DarXyde Sorry, your comment didnt expand so I only read: ```My opinion is that you are trying to resolve a prolem in VBA the same way you would do it in Excel... which kind of defeats the purpose,```. I will read up on arrays then, thank you!

Comment: It was my bad, pressed Enter to go next line (keep forgetting it doesn't work in comments)... I'll try to build an example on your code if i get the time (and no one else gets ahead...).

Comment: @DarXyde Greatly appreciated friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a dictionary of the Datasheet values using columns B & D joined as the key and column E as the item. This will provide virtually instantaneous 'two-column' lookup for the C15:AU29 table on the Exportsheet worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PopulateQIMs()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, ds As Object
    Dim arr As Variant, typ As Variant, art As Variant, k As Variant

    Set ds = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    'populate a dictionary
    With Worksheets("datasheet")

        'collect values from ws into array
        arr = .Range(.Cells(3, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)).Value2

        'cycle through array and build dictionary
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            'shorthand overwrite method of creating dictionary entries
            'key as join(column B & column D), item as column E
            ds.Item(Join(Array(arr(i, 1), arr(i, 3)), Chr(0))) = arr(i, 4)
        Next i

    End With

    With Worksheets("exportsheet")

        'collect exportsheet 'Type' into array
        'typ = .Range(.Cells(1, "C"), .Cells(1, "AU")).Value2
        typ = .Range(.Cells(1, "C"), .Cells(1, "C").End(xlToRight)).Value2

        'collect exportsheet 'Article Number' into array
        'art = .Range(.Cells(15, "AY"), .Cells(29, "AY")).Value2
        art = .Range(.Cells(15, "AY"), .Cells(15, "AY").End(xlDown)).Value2

        'create array to hold C15:AU29 values
        'ReDim arr(1 To 15, 1 To 45)
        ReDim arr(LBound(art, 1) To UBound(art, 1), _
                  LBound(typ, 2) To UBound(typ, 2))

        'cycle through Type and Article Numbers and populate array from dictionary
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)

                'build a key for lookup
                k = Join(Array(art(i, 1), typ(1, j)), Chr(0))

                'is it found ...?
                If ds.exists(k) Then

                    'put 'Quantity In Machine' into array
                    arr(i, j) = ds.Item(k)

                End If
            Next j
        Next i

        'put array values into Exportsheet
        .Cells(15, "C").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I have never used dictionary before but I will try this. **Thank you user!**

Comment: `build a key for lookup
k = Join(Array(art(i, 1), typ(1, j)), Chr(0))` This particular like gives me `Subscript out of range (Error 9)` How would I go about and fix this? I am not familiar with arrays (am trying to become more familiar!)

Comment: You must have changed the array dimensions that I copied from your sample. When you go into Debug and hover over `i` and `j`, what are `i` and `j`?

Comment: `i=1` and `j=46`

Comment: Yeah, you're out of bounds on the array. If you select the merged cell at C1 and tap `Ctrl+right arrow` do you go to the end of the Type row? If you go to AY15 and tap `Ctrl+down arrow` do you go to the end of the Article Numbers?

Comment: Both yes. The amount of type's can change so I have changed those `column numbers`  to a variable. `Lastrow-9` which, in this case, results in `column 47`.

Comment: Please see the edit I made above for dynamic allocation of the Types and Article Numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this exactly meets your needs, nor being the most elegant solution - and running out of time to make this more nicer...

It might not work for you straight out of the box, but i hope it gives you an idea on how to better aproach this.

```
Sub test()

'set all sheets
'----------------------------------------
Dim Isht As Worksheet
Dim Esht As Worksheet
Dim Dsht As Worksheet
Dim Gsht As Worksheet

Set Isht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Instructionsheet")
Set Esht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Exportsheet")
Set Dsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Datasheet")
Set Gsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Gathersheet")
'----------------------------------------

Dim EshtLR As Long
Dim EshtLC As Long
Dim DshtLC As Long
Dim DshtLR As Long

Dim OutputRange As Range
Dim SearchRange As Range
Dim MachineMatchCOL As Range
Dim ArticleMatchCOL As Range
Dim MachineType As String
Dim ArticleNumber As String

Dim StartRow As Long
Dim StartCol As Long

StartCol = Dsht.Range("P10").Value
StartRow = Dsht.Range("P11").Value

'Determine Last column in export sheet.
EshtLC = Esht.Cells(14, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'Determine Last row in data sheet.
DshtLR = Dsht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
'Determine Last row in export sheet.
EshtLR = Esht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

'Declare and allocate your ranges to arrays
Dim arrOutput As Variant, arrSearch As Variant

arrOutput = Esht.Range(Esht.Cells(1, 3), Esht.Cells(EshtLR, EshtLC))    'Not sure what last column is here, but i will make a presumption below that "Article number" is last
arrSearch = Dsht.Range(Dsht.Cells(1, 2), Dsht.Cells(DshtLR, 5))

Dim R As Long, C As Long, X As Long

For R = LBound(arrOutput) To UBound(arrOutput)
    For C = LBound(arrOutput, 2) To UBound(arrOutput, 2)

        For X = LBound(arrSearch) To UBound(arrSearch)

            'If the article number has a match in the search
            If arrOutput(R, UBound(arrOutput)) = arrSearch(X, 1) Then   'replace UBound(arrOutput) with the "Article number" column number
               'Let's check if the machine number is there as well
                If arrOutput(1, C) = arrSearch(X, 3) Then
                    'both found at the same row, return the value from that row
                    arrOutput(R, C) = arrSearch(X, 4)
                End If
            End If
        Next X
    Next C
Next R

End Sub
```

PS: You still need to write the values back to the sheet from the array, which you can either do directly `range = array` or through a loop, depending on your needs.

I`ll try to complete the answer later when i get more time (at work!).

Comment: I will try this! **Thanks DarXyde**